# gon is not defined error in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

pretty simple question. I'm trying to use gon. I set the variable in the controller like this:

```
gon.preference = "hello"
```

and in my .js.erb file, I try to use the variable like this:

```
console.log(gon.preference)
```

but I get an error saying that "gon is not defined". What could be the problem? Obviously rails recognizes that there is a gon variable. the .js.erb file is in my assets/javascripts directory. I tried changing the file name to .js (though I didn't expect this to make a difference at all). obviously no change.

No clue why gon is just not working!

Help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good answers here but figured out what was going on exactly. I was rendering a particular view without layout multiple times. However, since I was not rendering the layout while re-rendering this view, the `<%= include_gon %>` line in *application.html.erb* was useless.

I put `<%= include_gon %>` directly into the view I'm rendering, and everything works fine now!

Comment: I worked on this for hours and bypassed over this solution because I thought it couldn't be my problem... needless to say, this was the solution. Thanks man!

Comment: in 2022, send variables as global can be a workaround too.  gon.global.variable = 'Some data'

Answer (score 6):

I found adding this to your header helps.

```
<%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
```

Works great for rails 4 as well.

Comment: I'm upvoting this out of the serendipity that I'm looking for some reference on Gon the day you posted this ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I created a test project to attempt to see if I have the same problem, Which I DID!

Solution add the tag `<%= include_gon %>` in your header within `application.html.erb`:

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <%= include_gon %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

---

In the view:

```
console.log(gon.preference)
```

In the controller:

```
gon.preference = "hello"
```

Output:
[image]

---

Read more [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/gon/4.1.1/frames)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Ringo's solution would be to leave the statement in the application layout file, simply modifying it as follows:

```
<%= include_gon if defined? gon && gon.present? %>
```

This keeps the `include_gon` reference as DRY as possible while still being as flexible and unobtrusive.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message and also used user456584's answer but the error message remained. Once I added gon.event = @event or gon.events = @events as below in the controller, I guess gon became defined and therefore, I no longer had the error message "gon is not defined".

```
def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    gon.events = @events
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
end
```

I am a new user and I was only trying to contribute. This was the only method that worked for me after all other suggestions.

Comment: How does this pertain to the issue described by the OP? You've described a different problem and solution. Perhaps it's better to find a question where this actually fits.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across what I think is the same issue myself, and I'm wondering if the include_gon call should be in the body rather than the header of the application.html.erb.  Putting a js alert in both the header and body of application.html.erb shows that the header is not always invoked, while the body is.

I was experiencing a lack of gon if I initially loaded a page on my site other than the one that used it, and then navigated there via header links, but if I initially loaded the gon-using page, the site would work fine until a reload on any other page.

Moving include_gon from the header to the body of the layout seems to have fixed this.  I realize this is not how the gon docs suggest this should be done, but I'm not understanding how it would work the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happened to me

The `<% include_gon %>` was in the *application.html.erb* but was still getting this error.

The final reason was that in the **controller** the **name of the method** were I set the gon variables did not match the **route** of view. So the controller method was not being called before rendering the view and it seems that **gon** is only included when is used (which is great)

To solve it, in my case I just needed to make sure that the *routes.rb* route and the name of the Controler/Method matched

Comment: Could you show and example of how you did this please?

Comment: @mogoli I no longer have access to the specific code. Just make sure that the controller/method matches the URL that you are testing (including a breakpoint or debug message inside the method of the controller might help)

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
<%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
```

to the `head` section of your `application.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem recently and my solution was adding

```
if(window.gon != null) {
  ...
}
```

in my javascript file

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it's important to consider the **order** of loading gon and application javascript in `app/views/layout/application.html.slim` header.

I had to load gon **before** I load javascript like this:

```
doctype html
html lang= I18n.locale.to_s
  head
  meta charset='utf-8'
  meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
  title == content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : t('general.home')
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'

  = include_gon

  = javascript_include_tag 'application'
  = javascript_include_tag 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'
  = csrf_meta_tag
  = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
  body
    .main
      = render 'layouts/navbar'
      = render 'layouts/title', title: @title
      = render 'layouts/messages'
      = yield
```

Moving `= include_gon` after the `= javascript_include_tag 'applicaion'` raised the same error immediately.