# Rails URL parameter not recognized

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-parameters

In my Rails app, I'm trying to view a model via its' `URL /models/:id`.

I'm generating the URL two different ways: in `JavaScript` and `Rails`, though it seems to be randomly that the controller does not recognize the id-parameter in its' action.

**1st way in JavaScript:**

```
<a href='/conversations/" + conv_id + "'>" + conv_subject + "</a>
```

where conv_id is the id of the model I want to visit.

**Same bug occurs when I'm doing it the Rails way:**

```
<%= link_to "Conv" , conversation_path(22) %>
```

Where I've just put the id of the conversation by hand.

The controller action looks like this:

```
def show
   gon.current_user_id = current_user.id
   gon.conversation_id = params[:id]
 end
```

I'm displaying the contents via AJAX. There's more code handling that in the action.
The key point is, though, that the controller does not seem to recognize `params[:id]`.
Only after I pressed `F5`, after the first visit of `/conversations/:id`, the controller recognizes it.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

It happens that the controller recognizes the id, though `GON` wouldn't pass it to the javascript in time

**EDIT:**

The problem probably lies under the asset-pipeline, because all my scripts requiring `GON` are laying in the pipeline, which is only reloaded with the proper `GON-Variables`, after I've pressed `F5`

**EDIT:**

Since the problem lies in my JavaScript here's the approach I've taken so far. I tried to outsource all GON-Variables used in the Asset-Pipeline via function-parameters, which are passed to the functions in the views.

Asset-Pipeline function:

```
// Load n messages
function loadMessages(page, n, conv_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/conversations/ajax/fetch_messages',
        data: 'n=' + n + '&page=' + page + '&id=' + conv_id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'GET'
        ...
    });
}
```

View function:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        // Load 10 Messages when the page is loaded for the first time
        loadMessages(1, 10, gon.conversation_id);
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

This is what GON gives me when rails says it doesn't know the ID. It's kind of weird.

What the debugger tells me:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.gon={};gon.current_user_id=3;gon.conversation_id=22;
//]]>
```

What the inspector tells me:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.gon={};gon.load_n_feedbacks_path="/feedbacks/ajax/load_n_feedbacks";gon.user_id="3";
//]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been including `GON` via `include_gon` in my `application.html.erb`.

The html was not refreshing when clicking on links and thus weren't the GON-Variables. I simply followed this answer:
[gon is not defined error in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369063/gon-is-not-defined-error-in-javascript). It says to put all your `include_gon`s in the views who require it in their `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're passing a naked object to the `link_to` url option. Rails either needs a [URL helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), `:action` / `:controller` arguments or a pure URL

You're best using something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Conv" , conversation_path(22) %>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Made a big typo there when I posted the question ^.^ I'll edit my question

Comment: Thanks for update - have you tested the conversation_path way? I mean, is your path actually called `conversation_path`? I just used that as an example

Comment: Using the path method or the raw model does not make any difference, tbh. The link_to helper works both ways :-)

Comment: Okay, so your problem is with your javascript links?

Comment: Yes, I already tried to outsource all GON-Variables used in the asset-pipeline to function-parameters, which I pass to the functions in my views. I'll post an example

Comment: You know GON basically just renders JS-compatible variables on your page? There won't be any delay in loading them from JS, as they are basically just part of the HTML of the page

Comment: Yeah, I thought the asset pipeline loads all the assets once when visiting a page and only reloads it when reloading the whole page (F5) and as such using the right data for the GON-Variables

Comment: Thanks for the updates! Can you post the contents of your `<%= include_gon %>` in your HTML?