# Gon variable is undefined in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have been having lots of trouble passing variables from my Rails controller to JS/coffeescript and tried Gon as a last resort, but no luck.

My JS alert box shows undefined for gon.choices, but they show the correct output in the rails console from the controller.  Thoughts?

In my controller:

```
...
gon.choices = @choices
puts gon.choices
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :js => "test();"}
end
```

In my application.html.erb

```
<head>
...
<%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
<%= Gon::Base.render_data({}) %>
```

In my .js.coffee.erb file

```
window.test = ->
  alert gon.choices
```

[gon is not defined error in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369063/gon-is-not-defined-error-in-javascript)